# When did affix class change back to affix-top in bootstrap? Please help, still waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a right widget with id rightSideWidget.

```
<div data-spy="affix"  id="rightSideWidget" >
     // Some code here
</div>
```

I set my js as this:

```
if ($('#rightSideWidget').length > 0) {
    var
        topOffset = $('#rightSideWidget').offset().top;

        $('#rightSideWidget').affix({
            offset: {
                // I want the rightSideWidget to be affixed when it's 110px
                // from page top, because I have a fixed navbar at top
                // has 110 px height
                top: topOffset - 110
            }
        })
        .on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function() {
            window.console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        });
}
```

This code works fine, the rightSideWidget has a class affix-top when page load, and when it's 110px from page top, the class change from affix-top to affix, which is I expected.

[Please check the video here](http://screencast.com/t/QVB7RhRmFZ), remember to scroll down to view the class change:

But when I scroll up, the rightSideWidget's class affix didn't change back to affix-top when it's 110px from page top.

**What I did:**

I console log the point where it change back to affix-top, around 55px, [please check this video.](http://screencast.com/t/rdP5Eq1ud1)

**What I want:**

I want to rightSideWidget change back to affix-top exactly where it become affix, which in this case, 110px.

I know how to set this class manually when the rightSideWidge it's 110px from page top via jQuery, but I think it's NOT designed to make people do this manually, bootstrap affix should works fine by itself.

So any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.